# Zabbix web monitoring too frequent timeouts

Tags: timeout, zabbix

I have zabbix web monitoring setup and some steps timeout too frequently. When I make the requests from postman, the requests are actually faster and I do get a response back. Any ideas what might be going wrong? I have 5 scenarios setup for 5 different servers. Most of them run every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Try explaining the error on the (zabbix log) that you get while the web monitoring timeouts. Also check that the server and agent timeouts are not defined in your config file default is 3. If so then increase the value to prevent it from timeout.

Also look into the url for enabling some simple checks for web monitoring

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/simple_checks